# Accessing JSON elements of an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am returning a List of JSON items back from the front end. It current looks like:

```
[
  "[{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cbcd80e0c5c9f1dfc8bf2f3"), "price" : "$1,
  399.00", "name" : "AlienwareGamingPCDesktopAuroraR7-8thGenIntelCorei7-8700,
  16GBDDR4Memory,
  2TBHardDrive+32GBIntelOptane,
  ?NVIDIAGeForceGTX10808GBGDDR5X,
  Windows1064bit\", "url" : "https: //www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076BHG74V/ref=s9_acsd_zwish_hd_bw_b2N0U_>c_x_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_r=TW0CMS0QN07XT2BM838T&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=62f4ca32-9706-51c1-a1d1-9f7214564c34&pf_rd_i=565098\", "description" : "ThenewAlienwareAuroraisamid-towerdesktopwithaMicroATXmotherboardandisalsooursmallestdual-graphicscapabledesktopandhasmoretool-lessfeaturesthananypreviousAlienwaredesktopsuchas: tool-lessgraphics,
  expansioncards,
  hard>drives,
  andmemory.", "keywords" : ["computer"] }]"
]
```

When displaying the results with: console.log(results[0]), it displays the whole object. When doing console.log(results[0].name) or console.log(results[0].name) I get a undefined error. There is current only one object in the list, but for future queries there will be more. Any ideas on how to access individual elements?

What the code in the frontend looks like:

```
.then(response => {
            this.amazonItems = response.data;
            console.log(this.amazonItems[0]);
```

Query of MongoDB:

```
var result = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).ToList().ToJson();
```

Serialization:

```
List<string> returnResult = new List<string>();
returnResult.Add(_sm.SearchAmazonQuery(searchQuery, _db));
response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnResult), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
return response;
```

Console output: 
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RGJP.png)

Comment: Too much [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: Please show screenshots of your console, copying its output as text isn't always clear. Also, how are you creating the request?

Comment: From your comment below, what is `returnResult`? I suspect it's a list / array / collection / whatever of already JSON-encoded strings which would be why you're getting this double-encoded response

Comment: @Phil I added a answer....provided more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing, I think it is in stringify mode.

```
.then(response => {
    this.amazonItems = response.data;
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.amazonItems[0]));
```

Comment: FYI, it's `JSON.parse` (lowercase "p"). Also, I suspect OP's response is double JSON encoded, otherwise `amazonItems[0]` wouldn't work

Comment: I forgot to add, I serialize the list on the backend to JSON, so parsing wont work. 
response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnResult), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it’s stringified, try JSON.parse(results[0]), also that’s some weird syntax ObjectId(‘asdajdjsja’)

Comment: `ObjectId` indicates the response is a MongoDB doc entry

Comment: Correct, its coming from Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about your server-side code (guessing C#) but, assuming

```cs
_sm.SearchAmazonQuery(searchQuery, _db)
```

returns the result of

```js
var result = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).ToList().ToJson();
```

which appears to already be a JSON string, I suspect you just want

```cs
response.Content = new StringContent(_sm.SearchAmazonQuery(searchQuery, _db), 
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

This means your `response.data` will be an array of objects, not an array of JSON strings.

```js
.then(response => {
  this.amazonItems = response.data
  console.log(this.amazonItems[0])
    //  {_id: "5cbcd80e0c5c9f1dfc8bf2f3", price: "$1,399.00", ...
})
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions. I tried your fix, the result of console.log(amazonItems) is now just the same as the result from the image. Doing console.log(amazonItems[0] results in a single ' [ ' and amazonItems.name is results in undefined.

Comment: That's odd as Axios should be decoding the response as JSON automatically

Comment: Not sure what else to do. Wouldn't be so bad if I could access the elements.

Comment: We'll need to see exactly what the response is. Use your browser's _Network_ console. Check the response headers and please show exactly what the response body looks like